# Why is there an error in indexing in this Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPVoL.png) and code bits:

```
states = pd.DataFrame(census_df['STNAME'],census_df['COUNTY'] ,)
index = census_df(['STNAME'])
```

Statename and county have equal length but it is showing error.

```
Error  : __init__() got multiple values for argument 'index'
```

Can please anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want `STNAME` to be both an index and a column, then you are missing `[]` brackets. Try:

```
states = pd.DataFrame([census_df['STNAME'],census_df['COUNTY']] , index =    census_df['STNAME'] )
```

If you mean that you want `STNAME` as index and `COUNTY` as a column then you want either

```
states = pd.DataFrame(census_df['COUNTY'], index = census_df['STNAME'] )
```

or

```
states = pd.Series(census_df['COUNTY'], index = census_df['STNAME'] )
```

depending on whether you want to work with a `Series` or a `DataFrame` object.

Comment: Now it is just showing NAN values in front of each state

Comment: Click on the link. I am new to stack and can't paste images so they have upload as a link

Comment: You are getting Nans because the index 'Alabama' has duplicate county values. Are you sure that's the way you want to index? Wouldn't it make more sense to do `pd.DataFrame(census_df['STNAME'], index = census_df['COUNTY'] , columns=['STNAME'])`?

Comment: what i actually wanted to do was to group the counties by their state and find which state has how many counties

Comment: That's a different thing. Then you just want: `census_df.groupby('STNAME').COUNTY.nunique()`

Comment: @VarunSaxena, Now you told us what to do. Just use groupy(). Shown by splinter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
states = pd.DataFrame(census_df['STNAME'],census_df['COUNTY'])
states = states.set_index(census_df['STNAME'])
```

Comment: @VarunSaxena, paste your sample dataframe, so that it will help us to understand clearly.

Comment: Click on the link. I am new to stack and can't paste images so they have upload as a link